# Copy paste not working on Ubuntu machine while connecting from xrdp

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, xrdp

I have two machines, one windows 7 and other is Ubuntu. The Ubuntu machine has xrdp service running and I am using mstsc from windows machine to connect to Ubuntu machine

I able to connect but unable to copy anything to clipboard, not able to use tab button on Ubuntu and even Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V is not working.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This should fix your Tab issue.
Open ‘Settings> Window Manager’ from Start menu.  Then remove the 'Super-Tab' shortcut from the Keyboard section.  Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, it didn't work for me.